# Map to drive on another PC using net use - is passing password insecure?

Tags: windows-xp, security, passwords, network-shares

When running the following from the command line in Windows XP (to another XP machine):

```
net use "\\IP\c$" MyPassword /user:TheUser
```

Is the password passed securely? If not, is there a secure way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will be seen by any packet sniffing tool out there.  However, Net Use "\ip\c$\" should attempt to authenticate you as the current logged in user. if that does not work, (or you manually specify a different user with /user:theUser) a password prompt should pop up.  That should be secure.  Just click "remember this password"

Comment: Out of interest: How does Windows hide the password when it passes it from the password prompt?

Comment: it does not actually pass the password, but a 'hash' of the password.  It can then compare the hash it received to the one that is stored for that user. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) for an explanation of hashes.